# Stop and start a BizTalk 2009 application programmatically?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

Is there a way to stop and start a BizTalk application programmatically?

Ideally something that can be run in a script or batch file and as simple as possible?

I've looked at WMI, but from what I read it isn't able to stop and start Applications?  Is this true?

I've also looked at ExplorerOM, but does it work in 64-bit environments?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to run it via script or batch file the [PowerShell provider for BizTalk](http://psbiztalk.codeplex.com/) should be a good fit for you.